# Replace pattern between several string delimiters in PHP - Use of backreferences

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have the following string in PHP:

```
 $string = "<img src=\"url\" >HELLO WORLD<ol>I must replace the text after img and before ol.</ol>";
 print htmlentities($string);
```

I want to find the substring HELLO WORLD (*or whatever substring is, that is just an example of a text that will be completely dynamical*), using the delimiters : "<img ... >" and "<ol>" and add <h3> delimiters. So the string above would result in:

```
 <img src="url" ><h3>HELLO WORLD</h3><ol>I must replace the text after img and before ol.</ol>
```

I have tried the following code, of course with no success:

```
 $string = preg_replace("/\<img (.*?)\> (.*?)\<ol\>/", "<img  (.*?)><h3> (.*?)</h3></ol>", $string);
```

I know how to make very easy substituions, but the above condition is very far from my understanding.

Comment: You could use strpos, find the position of HELLO WORLD in the string, place </h3> at position + length of HELLO WORLD and after that place <h3> at the found position. strpos http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: @namlik This doesn't answer the question as the OP has clearly mentioned that OP wants to search HELLO WORD between "<img>" and "<op>" tags only.

Comment: @namlik is right. I must stress that I don't know that I will find HELLO WORLD, it could be any string. This is why I am using regular expressions. Strpos is not valid as I should know that I am going to find "HELLO WORLD".

Comment: It is more specific, in fact the question would be the use of backreferences, in the form of variables $n, with n = 1,...,99.

Comment: @Indrajit take a look at the post before the edit, you'll see that the part about (wathever substring it is) has been added later.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer by trial-and-error:

```
 $string = "<img src=\"url\" >HELLO WORLD<ol>I must find the text after img and before ol.</ol>";

 $string2 = preg_replace("/<img (.*?)>(.*?)<ol>/", "<img $1><h3>$2</h3><ol>", $string);
 print htmlentities($string) . " <br />" . htmlentities($string2);
```

Explanation: I add the delimiters, and use $1 and $2 for matching the results between the delimiters in the right order.

Comment: You're missing the `<ol>`

Comment: Thanks for the warning.

Comment: also, you don't need \ before  `<` and `>`